# nginx rewrite version assets

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Help me please. I use nginx and my problem with rewrite.
I have in html code this link http://example.com/admin/assets/123/css/main.css
123 - it`s version of assets
How i can rewrite this path? to http://example.com/admin/assets/css/main.css

I try rule but not work

```
location ~ /assets/(.*)$ {
 rewrite "/[0-9]{3}" /assets/$1 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture both parts of the URI, before and after the sequence you wish to delete.

```
rewrite "^(.*/assets/)[0-9]{3}/(.*)$" $1$2 last;
```

It is not necessary to place it inside a regular expression `location` block.